# Knockout.Validation Unusable, Any Alternatives? Or Workarounds?

Tags: validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm searching for a knockout validation plugin and I stumbled upon knockout.validation which looks very promising, however, it has a fatal flaw..

Once you have created a ko.validatedObservable({ name: foo }) you are not able to assign a new object to that observable.

For Example: In my view model I instantiate a validated observable.

```
var item = new ko.validatedObservable(new Tag({}));
```

I am then able to call:

```
item().isValid(); //Returns false in this case because Tag is empty
```

Tag looks like this

```
Model.Tag = function (data) {
    var
        Id = ko.observable(data.Id),
        Name = ko.observable(data.Name).extend({ required: true, maxLength: 64 }),
        Description = ko.observable(data.Description).extend({ required: true, maxLength: 512 });

    return {
        Id: Id,
        Name: Name,
        Description: Description
    };
};
```

The issue is if I wanted to get a new tag from the server and then modify that tag..

```
        $.ajax({
            url: API + "/" + id,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: Timeout,
            statusCode: {
                200: function(response) { item(response); },  //Here is where the bug is!
                404: ItemNotFound
            },
            error: function () {
                Item(new Type({}));
            }
        });
```

item now contains the value from the server, however, when I run

```
item().isValid();  //False is returned
```

This is listed as bug #209 on the GitHub project https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/issues?state=open.

Does anyone know of an elegant work around?  Or of another plugin that will accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how elegant it is, and maybe this is not the best solution (or not a solution at all) so use it at your own risk.

But you can override the `ko.validatedObservable` with a "fixed" version:

```
ko.validatedObservable = function (initialValue) {
    if (!ko.validation.utils.isObject(initialValue)) {
            return ko.observable(initialValue).extend({ validatable: true });
    }

    var obsv = ko.observable(initialValue);
    obsv.lastErrors = ko.observable(ko.validation.group(initialValue));    
    obsv.subscribe(function(newValue){             
        obsv.lastErrors(ko.validation.group(newValue));
    });
    obsv.errors = function() {        
        return obsv.lastErrors()();
    };
    obsv.isValid = ko.computed(function () {
       return obsv.errors().length === 0;
    });   

    return obsv;
};
```

My fix stores the result of the `ko.validation.group` call and recalculates it when the underlying `obsv` observable changes and I've also changed the [original errors property](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/Dist/knockout.validation.js#L1036) to use the `lastErrors` property.

I've update the sample from the [github issue](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/issues/209) you check in this demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VtJ5V/).

Comment: @nemsev thank you so much for this response, this resolves the issue.  My unit tests all pass now.  Do you know what is involved with updating the project on git-hub?  I guess I could just provide a link here with the bug resolution.  Thanks again!

Comment: Any improvements to this? It does not work if the initial value is undefined, when declaring the validatedObservable. I've modified it to support this scenario, but I'm not sure if there's a better alternative? https://gist.github.com/thj-dk/1f243519bfc2954bca60

Comment: @TommyJakobsen it seems this part of the plugin hasn't been changed: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/98a25714560e321779cbe6779d00ee4343871add/Src/ko.extensions.js. So currently this is the solution. However you can create an issue/pull request on Github with your improved fix and the description of this issue.